# WiX How to remove a component marked as permanent

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am in the following situation where I need to remove a component which is marked as permanent.
A previous version of our setup installs a windows service which should be left on the system after the main product was uninstalled.

Now we try to remove the left service and replace it with an updated version. The problem is we have two different component guids out there, because of changing the tools we used to create the msi's.

In my opinion there are three possible ways to achieve the goal:

a) Use a file search to update the files itself.
b) Use a component search and try to find it. If it was not found try to find the other one. If any one found use the upgrade element to upgrade the component.
c) ??? - probably the "best practice" way

Some of my fellows mentioned to only delete the files but this would cause more trouble because of the not unregistered component in the Windows Installer registry.

I don't mentioned CustomActions here because it should be the last option the achieve the goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option here is to open your old MSI using [InstEd It!](http://www.instedit.com/) or Orca and then copy the Component GUIDs and use them in your new installer.

This way WindowsInstaller will handle the upgrade for you. Obviously this will very painful if you have hundreds of Components that are set as permanent (you only need to bother about the permanent ones), but if it's a just the service element it should be a fairly easy task.

Also make sure your UpgradeCode is transferred across and do a [MajorUpgrade](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/major_upgrade.htm) so that your old installer is un-installed first.

Comment: Thanks for your replay @caveman_dick. I did it like you said. And no, we talk about to different Component Ids so it wasn't that painful.

To prevent this problem I will provide a merge module which should be added to every setup that needs this service.

Comment: Good idea with the merge module! :)